# How does Camel aggregator work

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a simple route with an aggregator.

```
---[processor]---[aggregator]---[processor]---...
```

What if I have 4 items passing the route in the following order - `itemA1, itemB1, itemA2 and itemB2`?

I want to merge `itemA1` with `itemA2` and `itemB1` with `itemB2`. How does the aggregator works when the two first items don't merge?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on aggregation here? http://camel.apache.org/aggregator.html#Aggregator-Usingcustomaggregationstrategy

Comment: If you have the Camel in Action book it has a very detailed explanation of this pattern and how it works.

Comment: @Adam Yes I have looked at it. But the documentation didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the advice from @Claus Ibsen I have find my answer in the book he recommended. The original documentation is very rudimentary.

```
itemA1 -> [item_type][item_number]
```

For the aggregator you have to specify the following three configurations:

- Correlation identifier - to identify which messages belongs together. In my case that could be the `item_type` field, so that all `A-items` belongs togehter and all `B-items`.
- Completion condition - a predicate or time-based condition that determines when the result message should be sent. For my example that could be a condition `completionSize(2)`.
- Aggregation strategy - to specify how to combine the aggregated result messages. E.g. join both items togehter like `itemA1itemA2` and `itemB1itemB2`

For any reason there is never published a second item of a type, the first item will stay inside the aggregator. But it is also possible to set timeouts and so on.